# Blitting / Loading PNG image in Pyglet resulting in "blotchy" image with an odd alpha layer

Tags: python, image, python-3.x, pyglet

I'm trying to display a PNG image in pyglet. The PNG image is this:  [image: Image to display]

However, when I attempt to render this using the following code:

```
if fullscreen:
    window = pyglet.window.Window(caption = "Forsaken Light, by Damian Heaton",
                                  fullscreen = True)
else:
    window = pyglet.window.Window(caption = "Forsaken Light, by Damian Heaton",
                                  fullscreen = False,
                                  width = 500, height = 250)
window.set_icon(pyglet.image.load('icon.ico'))

logo = pyglet.image.load(
    os.path.join("res", "graphics", "temp", "misc", "logo.png"))

class MenuEventHandler(object):
    def on_draw(self):
        window.clear()
        logo.blit((window.width / 2) - (logo.width / 2),
                  window.height - logo.height)

    def on_key_press(self, symbol, modifiers):
        if symbol == key.ESCAPE:
            sys.exit(0)
        return True

    def on_mouse_press(self, x, y, button, modifiers):
        print("Mouse button pressed in menu")
        return True

menu_handlers = MenuEventHandler()

window.push_handlers(menu_handlers)

def stop_game():
    window.pop_handlers()

pyglet.app.run()
```

It shows as this:
[image]

I've tried searching for what my problem is, but all example scripts using Pyglet rendering a PNG image seem to suggest my code is correct...

Any help would be appreciated, and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're still looking for it, here goes.

Since it is a PNG image, you can't just put it there on the window as it will lose its transparency. You need to import the PNGImageDecoder from pyglet like

`from pyglet.image.codecs.png import PNGImageDecoder`

then use it for loading the PNG image like

`kitten = pyglet.image.load('kitten.png', decoder=PNGImageDecoder())`

and finally draw it on the window by using

`kitten.draw()`, after specifying the x and y coordinates where you would like to have them.

The document for the above can be found [here](http://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/pyglet-1.2-maintenance/programming_guide/image.html).

Answer (score 0):

Add this to beginning of the on_draw function:

```
glEnable(GL_BLEND)
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)
```